# how to get the same required string with better and shorter way

Tags: python, string

```
s = 'myName.Country.myHeight'

required = s.split('.')[0]+'.'+s.split('.')[1]

print required
myName.Country
```

How can I get the same 'required' string with better and shorter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that seems just fine to me... But here are a few other ways I can think of :

```
required = ".".join(s.split(".")[0:2])  // only one split

// using regular expressions
import re
required = re.sub(r"\.[^\.]$", "", s)
```

The regex only works if there are no dots in the last part you want to split off.

Comment: -1 Raw `split` might be very inefficient here. Also, RegEx is overkill, for this simple problem.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) like this

```
s = 'myName.Country.myHeight'
print s.rpartition(".")[0]
# myName.Country
```

`rpartition` returns a three element tuple,

1. 1st element being the string before the separator
2. then the separator itself
3. and the the string after the separator

So, in our case,

```
s = 'myName.Country.myHeight'
print s.rpartition(".")
# ('myName.Country', '.', 'myHeight')
```

And we have picked only the first element.

**Note:** If you want to do it from the left, instead of doing it from the right, we have a sister function called [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition).

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options.

#### 1

```
print s.rsplit('.',1)[0]
```

#### 2

```
print s[:s.rfind('.')]
```

#### 3

```
print s.rpartition('.')[0]
```